# Trying to find the length of the polar curve $r=1-cos(\theta)$ with $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$, stuck on integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates, curves

As in the title, I'm trying to find the exact length of the $r=1-cos(\theta)$ with $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$ and I have it set up as so: $$L={\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{(1-cos \theta)^2+(-sin \theta)^2}}d \theta$$  But I can't figure out how to integrate this. Now, so you know what I understand, I'm familiar with trig identities and the basics of integration. Hopefully, that helps.

A u-substitution won't work here since there will be left-over non-constants, and I don't see any other way. I'm guessing that I will need to use some kind of trig-identity but I can't see it. I tried expanding $(1-cos \theta)^2$ but that still doesn't really help me.

Thank you to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta=2(1-\cos\theta)=2\cdot2\sin^2\dfrac{\theta}{2}$$

Comment: can I take the square-root of $4sin^2({\theta \over2})$? Or is that invalid?

Comment: Yes. ...........

Comment: Ok, here is what I have now: $${\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{4sin^2{{\theta} \over 2}}} d \theta$$ That equals: $$2 \int_0^{2 \pi}{sin{\theta \over 2}} d \theta$$ Eventually comes out to 2... I don't think that is correct.

Comment: Correct$$\int2\sin\dfrac{\theta}{2}d\theta=2\dfrac{-\cos\theta/2}{1/2}=-4\cos\dfrac{\theta}{2}$$

Comment: Couldn't I have done a u-sub as well (I think that is kind of what you did)? $$u={\theta \over 2}\;\;\; 2 \int sin(u) {2du} = -4cos({\theta \over 2})$$ That makes sense, so after putting the bounds in I should get 5?

Comment: The substitution makes it better, so do it and final answer will be $8$.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome!